# Get values from database table with ID from Unity

Tags: php, sql, unity-game-engine

I have a database table with values, the primary key being ID. Now I am trying to receive the values of the table with the referenced ID from Unity. How do I send the referenced ID from Unity to this php file so that only the values from this ID should be received.

Currently I am receiving all the values of the table from all IDs.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;

public class CheckForExistingID : MonoBehaviour {
    public string[] Items;
    public string ID = "001"; //Referenced ID

    public string Name;
    public string Age;

    void Start () {
            StartCoroutine (ReceiveValues());
        }

    IEnumerator ReceiveValues () {
        WWW data = new WWW ("http://localhost/GetValue.php?id="+ID);
        yield return data;

        if (data.error != null) {
            print (data.error);
        } else {
            print ("Received");
            dataString = data.text;

            Items = dataString.Split (';');

            Name = Items[0];
            Age = Items[1];
         }
   }
}
```

GetValue.php

```
<?php
 
...
...
...

$id = $_GET['id'];

$sql = "SELECT Name, Age FROM Students WHERE ID = $id";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            echo "".$row['Name'] . ";";
            echo "".$row['Age'] . ";";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Actually you shouldn't use [`WWW`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) at all anymore .. it is legacy and *obsolete* .. you should rather use a [`UnityWebRequest.Post`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Post.html) and in php use `$_POST['id']` instead ... aaaand well hello [**SQL INJECTION!!**](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) -> **Use prepared statements instead!!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE** Do **NOT** use **WWW** as derHugo had pointed out, it is now obsolete. Similarly sanitize all data using prepared statements. Skip to the **edit** marker to find an updated answer.

I am not sure you are posting the data properly. You should use a [`WWWForm`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWWForm.html), add the fields you want and then handle them on the PHP side. I would also heavily consider adding some form of error handling in PHP with an echo to know if something failed.

On mobile so excuse the formatting for now I'll fix it later if it needs it.

```
string url = "http://localhost/GetValue.php";
WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
form.AddField("id", "TheIDHere");
WWW www = new WWW(url, form);
yield return www;
...
```

On the PHP side of things, it can look like

```
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST["id"])) {
    echo "Received ". $_REQUEST["id"]. " success!";
    exit();
} else {
    http_status_code(400);
    echo "Request Failed";
}
```

**Edit:** As pointed out by derHugo, `WWW` is now obsolete, and is replaced by `WebRequests`. The above c# code should look like

```
WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
form.AddField("id", "yourID");

UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("http://localhost/GetValue.php", form);
yield return www.SendWebRequest();

if (www.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
{
    Debug.Log(www.error);
}
else
{
    Debug.Log("Sucess");
}
```

As well, derHugo had pointed out that you are not sanitizing your data at all, so you would be subject to SQL Injections. Here is roughly what you would want to do to use prepared statements

```
// prepare a statement using the ID
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT Name, Age FROM Students WHERE ID = ?");

// bind the ID from our POST
$stmt->bind_param("i", $_POST['id']);

// execute our prepare statement
$stmt->execute();

// store the result
$stmt->store_result();

// we have no found id
if($stmt->num_rows === 0) exit('No Data');

// bind the results we are looking for from our prepared statement
$stmt->bind_result($idName, $idAge); 

// fetch the results from the table
$stmt->fetch();

// echo your results to Unity
echo $idName;
echo $idAge;

// deallocate the statement 
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: OP is using `GET` with URL fields which is theoretically ok ... but actually you shouldn't use [`WWW`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) at all anymore .. it is legacy and *obsolete* .. you should rather use a [`UnityWebRequest.Post`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Post.html) and in php use `$_POST['id']` instead ... aaaand well hello [**SQL INJECTION!!**](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) -> **Use prepared statements instead!!** .. OP's PHP is absolutely dangerous and everything but fine ;)

Comment: @derHugo Oh gotcha I should have used `WebRequest` instead but just typed it up on mobile. I can rewrite the post using the updated class and can use prepared statements. I was not sure of the scope of OP's game, but best practice should be followed especially if it has to do with security. I can make an update to the post in a little bit - just not home right now.

Comment: @derHugo Alright updated the snippets - left the old ones in to show what not to do.